# Piping your current $PATH to VSCode as a shortcut

Tags: bash, shell, regex, zsh, visual-studio-code

My knowledge on shell usage, regular expressions and system processes is rather small. I know I can pipe de result of one command to another.

Yet doing `pwd | code` or `$PATH | code` doesn't yield the the result of doing cd to the directory I wish to open with VSCode and running `code .`

I've been told I can't do that, since I'm trying to "access the path from an external process". Is this correct? And, is there any way to achieve my desired result through a shell command that I can assign to a shortcut?

Thanks

Comment: Pipes do something quite a bit different from what you want here. What directory are you trying to move to? `pwd` prints where you already are, and `$PATH` is a list of places to look for command executables; neither makes sense as a place to move *to*.

Comment: @GordonDavisson looks like I'm worse at this than I thought, sorry. I find myself browsing via GUI (i.e: Nautilus) frequently to folders that I then want to open in VSCode.

What I usually do is traverse to the directory via GUI, open a terminal there (via "Open a terminal here" option), and then executing `code .`

I wanted to automate that with a simple shortcut, that is, traverse to a place via GUI, and then hitting a shortcut to open VSCode in that path.

Comment: It sounds like you want to look at Nautilus scripts or shortcuts, not regular shell scripts.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I'll look into that. Thanks for helping out a n00b :)

Answer (score 0):

As @GordonDavisson stated, I'd be better of looking into Nautilus plugins, scripts or shortcuts, not shell scripts or regex.